# Angular v5 Template Warning - Conditional in Expression

Tags: angular

I have the following conditional property binding for an `<img>` `scr` property:

```
<img  alt="About" class="profile-pic" 
         [src]="(blogPost && blogPost.authorProfilePictureURL) ? blogPost.authorProfilePictureURL : ''">
```

When this is in an inline template, the closing `>` shows up in **red**.

If it's in a separate `html` template file, the `&&` is displayed as a **red** warning.

They both compile, but is there something I'm missing here? The rest of my Component code or Template then shows up as being in error

**Update**

The empty quotes at the end of the conditional were causein the issue. I fixed this by wrapping the entire conditional expression in brackets. This works well

```
<img  alt="About" class="profile-pic"
         [src]="((blogPost && blogPost.authorProfilePictureURL) ? blogPost.authorProfilePictureURL : '')" >
```

Comment: What does it show when you hover over it ?

Comment: May be try updating visual code!

Comment: Had faced the same issue with some of extensions. Might want to check on that as wel

Comment: If it's checking as html, then it probably doesn't like`&&` as it assumes you mean `&amp;` and the `>` is probably highlighted since it expects html elements to have a `/` or closing tag (even though `<img>` doesn't need one as it's a void element).

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should should use the "safe navigation" operator, aka the "elvis operator" to simplify your template expression. You can re-write it as `[src]="blogPost?.authorProfilePictureURL"`

Comment: I think you could do `[src]="blogPost?.authorProfilePictureURL || ''"` in that case. Whatever works though.